# Can't ignore some files using typedoc with angularcli

Tags: angular, typedoc

I am trying to generate a documentation for my AngularCli App using typedoc.
The result is beautiful but I can't manage to ignore some files such as the .spec.ts and .css ones.

I used something like this

```
typedoc --out D:/path/to/doc  --module angular --exclude "*.spec.ts" "*.css" src/
```

and I encounter this kind of error

```
no such file or directory, stat 'D:\path\IdeaProjects\project\*.css'
```

cause each component has its own css file, in its own directory...

Someone has a solution ?

I have tried to write */*.css but it doesn't work...

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TypeDoc does not currently support multiple excludes but the minimatch expression it uses can support multiple options. Additionally, you will want to use the double star syntax to exclude recursively.

```
typedoc --out D:/path/to/doc --module angular --exclude "**/*.{spec.ts,css}" src/
```

For more information see [issue 395](https://github.com/TypeStrong/typedoc/issues/395) in the TypeDoc repo.